# Is there a better way of checking if the characters in index 1 and 2 match a particular requirement?

Tags: javascript

I am new to learning JavaScript. I just wondered if there is a better way of checking for a particular string starting from index 1.

This is how I solved the problem so far:

```js
function mixStart(str) {
  if (str[1] === 'i' && str[2] === 'x') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

//Examples
console.log(
  mixStart('mix snacks') // → true
,
  mixStart('pix snacks') // → true
,
  mixStart('piz snacks') // → false
);
```

Comment: `const mixStart = str => str.indexOf('ix') === 1;`

Comment: Also please do not use if and return true or false on something that returns a boolean: `function mixStart(str) { return str[1] === 'i' && str[2] === 'x' }`

Comment: "Better" is a subjective term (which makes things off-topic here), and in any case, better *how*? In terms of effort to write? Speed of execution? Memory impact? :-) <subjective>Have you have is simple, clear, fast, and has minimal memory impact. There are lots of *other* ways you could do it, but I'd struggle to call any of them "better." "Shorter," sure. :-) </subjective>

Comment: The answer in the first comment does not always work, for instance it would return false when checking for the substring `"aa"` in the string `"aaa"`

Answer (score 2):

```js
const mixStart = (str) => str.slice(1,3) === "ix"

//Examples
console.log(
  mixStart('mix snacks') // → true
,
  mixStart('pix snacks') // → true
,
  mixStart('piz snacks') // → false
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternatives:

1. [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) can be used to describe the pattern to test against the given string. Starting from the beginning with the marker `^`, we expect the characters `ix` after a first character (represented by `.`):

```js
function mixStart(str) {
  return /^.ix/.test(str);
}

//Examples
console.log(
  mixStart('mix snacks') // → true
,
  mixStart('pix snacks') // → true
,
  mixStart('piz snacks') // → false
);
```

2. As pointed by [Alireza Amini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74974465/6612932), you can rely on [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to check the start of your string, given an offset as second parameter to start from character 2:

```js
function mixStart(str) {
  return str.startsWith("ix", 1);
}

//Examples
console.log(
  mixStart('mix snacks') // → true
,
  mixStart('pix snacks') // → true
,
  mixStart('piz snacks') // → false
);
```

3. As pointed by [DanteDX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74974493/6612932), you can extract the substring to check with [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
function mixStart(str) {
  return str.slice(1, 3) === "ix";
}

//Examples
console.log(
  mixStart('mix snacks') // → true
,
  mixStart('pix snacks') // → true
,
  mixStart('piz snacks') // → false
);
```